# Can't register a user in a MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This code simply registers the user but it's not working, I would like if someone could just double check this code to make sure, I think it has a problem with the SQL lines where it has to insert the user to the DB.

**Users.php**

```
  public function register($email, $screenName, $password){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users ('email', 'password', 
  'screenName', 'profileImage', 'profileCover') VALUES  (:email, :password, 
  :screenName, 'assets/images/defaultProfileImage.png', 
  'assets/images/defaultCoverImage.png')");
  $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":password", md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":screenName", $screenName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();

  $user_id = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
  }
```

**Login.php**

```
    if(!filter_var($email)){
    $error = 'Invalid email format';
    }else if(strlen($screenName) > 20){
    $error = 'Name must be between 6-20 caracters long';
    }else if(strlen($password) < 5){
    $error = 'Password is too short';
    }else{
    if($getFromU->checkEmail($email) === true){
    $error = 'Email already in use';
    }else{
    $getFromU->register($email, $screenName, $password);
    header('Location: home.php')
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Does your script has display_errors "On". If there is a mysql error then it should give you a Fatal Error. Try seeing mysql error log or run the execute method inside try catch

Comment: No, it does not display any errors, my signup form displays inside of my page as a floating element and it's just hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use " ' " single quote to specify the column list in Insert statement, unless you created these column in case-sensitive.

If you columns are not in Case-sensitive then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password,screenName, profileImage, profileCover) VALUES  (:email, :password, 
  :screenName, 'assets/images/defaultProfileImage.png', 
  'assets/images/defaultCoverImage.png')
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work, it came up with a completely new error "Into" so some of them need to be in quotes id say.

Comment: By that I mean it gives an error "INTO" on login.php on line 50 if I paste the code you gave me, so I figured that some of the code needs to be in quotes for it to read it as an SQL insert.

Comment: Wait i did some searching in my code "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialBud\includes\signup-form.php on line 28"

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Turns out I had a syntax error ";".
Mysql also doesn't like the be enclosed in quotes since it is closterfobic. Thanks to everyone who helped!